# what is the type of a template referance variable passed as input?

Tags: angular

I do have following piece of (pseudo-) code

```html
<some-component   #someComponent/>

<another-component [reference]="someComponent" />
```

```js
@Component(...)
export class AnotherComponent {
 @Input() reference     // <--- type
}
```

My question now is: What is the type of the `Input` `reference`? I did not find anything in the docs. It is (as far as I can say) not an `ElementRef`. I do then want to access the `nativeElement` of the passed `reference`.

Comment: It's of type `SomeComponent`, but you can use "any" if you want (in both case you has access to all the public properties or functions of the component)

Comment: I absolutely want to avoid `any` because this will bring me no proper typing

Answer (score 2):

If it is always `#someComponent`, you could just use `SomeComponentComponent` or however your class is called.
If it is dynamic, you could use `TemplateRef<any>`

Comment: By using TemplateRef there's no access to the nativeElement unfortunately